# python random IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, random

i try to use this python code this but i dont know what wrong pls help

```
def bbl(size):
    out_str = ''
    for _ in range(0, size):
        a = random.randint(65, 160)
        out_str += chr(a)
    return(out_str)

def UserAgProces():
    global t_user_agent
    global t_referer_list
    param_joiner = '&'
    uat = open('randua.txt', 'r')
    rft = open('randrf.txt', 'r')
    t_user_agent = uat.read().splitlines()
    t_referer_list = uat.read().splitlines()
    uareq = urllib.request.Request(url + param_joiner + bbl(random.randint(3,10)) + '=' + bbl(random.randint(3,10)))
        uareq.add_header('User-Agent', random.choice(t_user_agent))
        uareq.add_header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache')
        uareq.add_header('Accept-Charset', 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7')
        uareq.add_header('Referer', random.choice(t_referer_list) + bbl(random.randint(50,100)))
        uareq.add_header('Keep-Alive', random.randint(110,160))
        uareq.add_header('Connection', 'keep-alive')
        uareq.add_header('Host',host)

url=input('Url Or IP (eg. http/s://www.example.com/) : ')
UserAgProces()
```

error i get when try to run this. can someone help me i confused whats wrong with this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 39, in <module>
    UserAgProces()
  File "main.py", line 33, in UserAgProces
    uareq.add_header('Referer', random.choice(t_referer_list) + bbl(random.randint(50,100)))
  File "random.py", line 347, in choice
    return seq[self._randbelow(len(seq))]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

randrf.txt (some random referer text)

```
http://www.google.com/?q=
http://www.usatoday.com/search/results?q=
http://engadget.search.aol.com/search?q=
http://www.google.com/?q=
http://www.usatoday.com/search/results?q=
http://engadget.search.aol.com/search?q=
http://www.bing.com/search?q=
http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=
http://www.ask.com/web?q=
http://search.lycos.com/web/?q=
http://busca.uol.com.br/web/?q=
http://us.yhs4.search.yahoo.com/yhs/search?p=
http://www.dmoz.org/search/search?q=
http://www.baidu.com.br/s?usm=1&rn=100&wd=
http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=
http://www.zhongsou.com/third?w=
http://hksearch.timway.com/search.php?query=
http://find.ezilon.com/search.php?q=
http://www.sogou.com/web?query=
http://api.duckduckgo.com/html/?q=
http://boorow.com/Pages/sitebraspx?query=
http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=
http://validator.w3.org/checklink?uri=
http://validator.w3.org/unicorn/check?ucntask=conformance&ucnuri=
http://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=
http://validator.w3.org/mobile/check?docAddr=
http://validator.w3.org/p3p/20020128/p3p.pl?uri=
http://www.icap2014.com/cms/sites/all/modules/ckeditorlink/proxy.php?url=
http://www.rssboard.org/rss-validator/check.cgi?url=
http://www2.ogs.state.ny.us/help/urlstatusgo.html?url=
http://prodvigator.bg/redirect.php?url=
http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=
http://www.ccm.edu/redirect/goto.asp?myURL=
http://forum.buffed.de/redirect.php?url=
http://rissa.kommune.no/engine/redirect.php?url=
http://www.sadsong.net/redirect.php?url=
https://www.fvsbank.com/redirect.php?url=
http://www.jerrywho.de/?s=/redirect.php?url=
http://www.inow.co.nz/redirect.php?url=
http://www.automation-drive.com/redirect.php?url=
http://mytinyfile.com/redirect.php?url=
http://ruforum.mt5.com/redirect.php?url=
http://www.websiteperformance.info/redirect.php?url=
http://www.airberlin.com/site/redirect.php?url=
http://www.rpz-ekhn.de/mail2date/ServiceCenter/redirect.php?url=
http://evoec.com/review/redirect.php?url=
http://www.crystalxp.net/redirect.php?url=
http://watchmovies.cba.pl/articles/includes/redirect.php?url=
http://www.seowizard.ir/redirect.php?url=
http://apke.ru/redirect.php?url=
http://seodrum.com/redirect.php?url=
http://redrool.com/redirect.php?url=
http://blog.eduzones.com/redirect.php?url=
http://www.onlineseoreportcard.com/redirect.php?url=
http://www.wickedfire.com/redirect.php?url=
http://searchtoday.info/redirect.php?url=
http://www.bobsoccer.ru/redirect.php?url=
```

randua.txt (some random user agent text)

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/37.0.2062.94 Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/600.8.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.8 Safari/600.8.9
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_4_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12H321 Safari/600.1.4
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10240
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/600.7.12 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.7 Safari/600.7.12
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/600.8.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.1.8 Safari/537.85.17
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12H143 Safari/600.1.4
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12F69 Safari/600.1.4
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/600.6.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.6 Safari/600.6.3
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/600.5.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.5 Safari/600.5.17
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_4_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12H321 Safari/600.1.4
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 7_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11D257 Safari/9537.53
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/6.0)
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 7077.134.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.156 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/600.7.12 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.1.7 Safari/537.85.16
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12B466 Safari/600.1.4
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/600.3.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.3 Safari/600.3.18
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12B440 Safari/600.1.4
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; en-us; KFTT Build/IML74K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Silk/3.68 like Chrome/39.0.2171.93 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12D508 Safari/600.1.4
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 7_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11D201 Safari/9537.53
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.3; en-us; KFTHWI Build/KTU84M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Silk/3.68 like Chrome/39.0.2171.93 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/600.6.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.1.6 Safari/537.85.15
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/600.4.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.4 Safari/600.4.10
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.78.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.6 Safari/537.78.2
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_4_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/45.0.2454.68 Mobile/12H321 Safari/600.1.4
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12B410 Safari/600.1.4
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 7_0_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11B554a Safari/9537.53
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; TNJB; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; ARM; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; MDDCJS; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12H143 Safari/600.1.4
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.3; en-us; KFASWI Build/KTU84M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Silk/3.68 like Chrome/39.0.2171.93 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_4_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) GSA/7.0.55539 Mobile/12H321 Safari/600.1.4
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.155 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12F70 Safari/600.1.4
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; MATBJS; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.4; en-us; KFJWI Build/IMM76D) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Silk/3.68 like Chrome/39.0.2171.93 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 7_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11D167 Safari/9537.53
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS armv7l 7077.134.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.156 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10) AppleWebKit/600.1.25 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Safari/600.1.25
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/600.2.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.2 Safari/600.2.5
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/600.1.25 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Safari/600.1.25
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11) AppleWebKit/601.1.56 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Safari/601.1.56
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.3; en-us; KFSOWI Build/KTU84M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Silk/3.68 like Chrome/39.0.2171.93 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 5_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9B206 Safari/7534.48.3
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12B435 Safari/600.1.4
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10240
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; LCJB; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; MDDRJS; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.3; en-us; KFAPWI Build/KTU84M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Silk/3.68 like Chrome/39.0.2171.93 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; LCJB; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; en-us; KFOT Build/IML74K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Silk/3.68 like Chrome/39.0.2171.93 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10B329 Safari/8536.25
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.3; en-us; KFARWI Build/KTU84M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Silk/3.68 like Chrome/39.0.2171.93 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; ASU2JS; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_0_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12A405 Safari/600.1.4
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/5.0)
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.77.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.5 Safari/537.77.4
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; yie11; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; MALNJS; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_4_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) GSA/8.0.57838 Mobile/12H321 Safari/600.1.4
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; MAGWJS; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/600.5.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.1.5 Safari/537.85.14
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.152 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; TNJB; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; NP06; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.155 Safari/537.36 OPR/31.0.1889.174
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/600.4.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.3 Safari/600.4.8
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 7_0_6 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11B651 Safari/9537.53
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/600.3.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.1.3 Safari/537.85.12
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko; Google Web Preview) Chrome/27.0.1453 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12A365 Safari/600.1.4
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.155 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 AOL/9.7 AOLBuild/4343.4049.US Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/45.0.2454.68 Mobile/12H143 Safari/600.1.4
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_4_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/12H321
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 7_0_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11B511 Safari/9537.53
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/600.1.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.1 Safari/537.85.10
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.130 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/600.2.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.1.2 Safari/537.85.11
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; ASU2JS; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008070208 Firefox/3.0.1
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; MDDCJS; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/534.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) Qt/4.8.5 Safari/534.34
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A465 Safari/9537.53 BingPreview/1.0b
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) GSA/7.0.55539 Mobile/12H143 Safari/600.1.4
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.155 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 7262.52.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.86 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.155 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; MDDCJS; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/600.4.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.1.4 Safari/537.85.13
Mozilla/5.0 (Unknown; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/538.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/2.0.0 Safari/538.1
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; MALNJS; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/45.0.2454.68 Mobile/12F69 Safari/600.1.4
Mozilla/5.0 (Android; Tablet; rv:40.0) Gecko/40.0 Firefox/40.0
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11D257 Safari/9537.53
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10) AppleWebKit/600.2.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0.2 Safari/600.2.5
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/536.30.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.5 Safari/536.30.1
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.125 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.3; en-us; KFSAWI Build/KTU84M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Silk/3.68 like Chrome/39.0.2171.93 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.104 AOL/9.8 AOLBuild/4346.13.US Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; MAAU; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.152 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.132 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.74.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.2 Safari/537.74.9
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.155 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 7_0_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A501 Safari/9537.53
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; MAARJS; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 7_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A465 Safari/9537.53
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) GSA/7.0.55539 Mobile/12F69 Safari/600.1.4
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.78.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.6 Safari/537.78.2
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; MASMJS; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.155 Safari/537.36 OPR/31.0.1889.174
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; FunWebProducts; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; MAARJS; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; BOIE9;ENUS; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; SM-T230NU Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.84 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; EIE10;ENUSWOL; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.4; en-us; KFJWA Build/IMM76D) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Silk/3.68 like Chrome/39.0.2171.93 Safari/537.36
```

I dont know what wrong i try another code but still have same error result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the problem:

```
t_user_agent = uat.read().splitlines()
t_referer_list = uat.read().splitlines()
```

After calling `uat.read()` once, the file is exhausted.  So when you call it the second time, it returns an empty list, and then later you call `random.choice()` on an empty list, which causes the error.

Did  you intend the second one to be `rft.read()` instead of another call to `uat.read()`?